# How to find the symbol that an object of the class add.add depends on?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this expression `−0.00117115487626846cos(ϕc)+0.00241553041801322` and it belongs to the type add.add from sympy, i have a list like this which depends on phic or phia, i want to test for several on which one depends. I have tried with in and args, but still not have the answer. Thanks

i hace tried args and in

```
return:  
 simplify(expand((u[0,2]*conjugate(u[0,2])).subs(constantes),complex=True))

S13=[]


for i in range(6):

    S13.append(s13(U[i]))
```

I expect the output gives me if the dependence is on phia or phic or both

Answer (score 1):

In general, the free symbols (those symbols on which an expression depends) are available through the free_symbols attribute.

So, you can do something like this:

```
from sympy import *
x,y = symbols('x y')
exp = x**2 + y**2 + x*y
s = exp.free_symbols
print(s) # {x,y}
```

Comment: and in case of functions? this expresion becomes from a function i previously  defined, is like phia and phic are implicit variables but the result is not a function, i think i am kind of lost in what sympy does when you evaluate a function in a symbol

Comment: Can you provide your function definition? Perhaps if you show more of your code, your question will become clearer